# How to transform a bootstrap modal into a non-blocking mdi window

Tags: bootstrap-modal, angular-bootstrap

I want the page to stay accessible with modal being opened. I have tried with possible values of backdrop

```
  this.modalService.open(firstWindow,
  {
    backdrop  : 'static',/*true, false*/
    keyboard  : false
  });
```

How do I implement a non blocking `modal` ?

Comment: The `backdrop` option is for when you want to dismiss the modal on empty clicks. Not for removing the modal background which covers the whole view. See the [modal component structure](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/).

Comment: a "modal" window is just that, focus only: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window I think what you are looking for is maybe a dialog box instead.

Comment: while you comments are important, can you consider to answer the question? how to transform a modal into an non-non blocking  dialog?